# Generic AJAX completed handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with a content management system that utilizes a number of different AJAX procedures for different functions.  I really don't want to start poking around the core procedures because what I need doesn't warrant the effort.

So here's my question.  Is there a *generic* JQuery on-completion handler that will detect if an AJAX call has been performed/was successful that I can utilize to launch a procedure without having to append to the return function of the specific query/process?

Comment: You mean a global `complete` handler for all your ajax calls? If so check [ajaxComplete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: there is, although `.then(fnSomethingElse)` isn't laborious to wire up and won't accidentally fire from a plugin or some other out-of-band IO.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a global `.ajaxComplete` event you can look into.

https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: There's also `$.ajaxSetup()` too, which doesn't need to be bound to the document.